# With Aspose Cells, how to copy a Cell formula to another cell and update its references in .Net Core without its formating

Tags: asp.net, excel, asp.net-core, aspose, aspose-cells

I'm using Aspose Cells with .net Core.

I would like to copy a cell formula to another cell and update the cells references in the formula with its new "location".

If I use the `cell.copy` it's working but It's copy also the cell attributes, like 'locked'.

Is there way around it?

Like when using MS-Excel and you do a “Special Paste Formula Only”

Comment: Hello did you tried `sheet.Cells[cellNo][1].FormulaR1C1` [You can check FormulaR1C1 official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.formular1c1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_FormulaR1C1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post my question on the Aspose Forum and got a quick answer from @[Amjad Sahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405358/amjad-sahi)

https://forum.aspose.com/t/copy-formula-from-a-cell-to-another-with-updated-references-without-the-source-cell-attribute-like-locked/239996/2

It's worked for me.

I end up with this:

```
    public void CopyFormulaFrom(ICell cell)
    {
        var cells = cell.Sheet.Name == Sheet.Name
            ? _cell.Worksheet.Cells
            : _cell.Worksheet.Workbook.Worksheets[cell.Sheet.Name]?.Cells;

        var cellSource = cells.CreateRange(cell.Row, cell.Column, 1, 1);
        var cellDestination = cells.CreateRange(_cell.Row, _cell.Column, 1, 1);
        
        var options = new PasteOptions() { PasteType = PasteType.Formulas };

        cellDestination.Copy(cellSource, options);
    }
```

Comment: good to know that you are up and running again :)
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.